# deserializing object for spacy [python]

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, spacy

I am trying to load an EntityRuler from a serialized object. The process of loading the object does not fail or anything, but I am sure it does not do it. I double-checked with try and except statement and it stills does not set the new rulers. I am not sure if it has to do with the EntityRuler.

This is how I am serializing:

```
def save_loc_rules(stations):
    print('Adding rules')
    for station in stations:
        ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "GPE", "pattern": station.lower()}])
    nlp.add_pipe(ruler)
    rules = ruler.to_bytes()
    with open("location_rules.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump((rules), f)
    print('Rules added')
```

and here is how am deserializing:

```
def load_loc_rules(ruler):
    #ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
    print('Loading location rules')
    with open("location_rules.pickle", "rb") as f:
        rules = pickle.load(f)
    print('Loading locations failed')
    #print('Location rules loaded')
    ruler = ruler.from_bytes(rules)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time on the documentation page, I realize that when I am loading the EntityRuler object I have to add it to the NLP pipe.
So after loading it I added :

```
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)
```